# Start from different html heading in Hakyll

Tags: haskell, pandoc, hakyll

I'm building a static website with Hakyll and I'm using the PandocCompiler to compile markdown to html. This works perfectly, but the compiler takes this:

```
# Heading 1
```

and compiles it to

```
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
```

This is the expected result. However, I'd like to start at a lower heading, say, `<h3>`, so that:

```
# Heading 1
```

compiles to

```
<h3>Heading 1</h3>
```

and this:

```
## Heading 2
```

compiles to

```
<h4>Heading 2</h4>
```

and so on.

I could of course change the markdown itself, but I have many files and it would be a lot of work, and it would make the markdown a bit uglier.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Whoever voted to close as "about general computing hardware and software" doesn't know what Hakyll is and didn't bother to check.

Comment: Possible alternative: instead of translating `# Heading 1` to `<h3>`, you might consider changing your CSS to make `h1`'s less pronounced. (Though I recognize there can also be legitimate reasons to avoid `h1` entirely.)

Comment: @DanielWagner I use h1 in the templates as a more general header title, and then want my markdown to generate the body. In other words, I do need the h1 too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Hakyll.Web.Html` module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hakyll-4.7.3.0/docs/Hakyll-Web-Html.html) includes some useful functions for HTML manipulation, including a `demoteHeaders` which should be enough for your needs. It is also worth noting that the `withTags` function there allows convenient usage of [*tagsoup*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tagsoup-0.13.3/) for arbitrary manipulation of HTML tags.